# Vue.js - Transfer focus to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus, aria-live

I have a form fragment wrapped in a component that is hidden by `v-if`. When the user clicks a button, it toggles the boolean, revealing the hidden component, and when that happens I'd like to transfer focus to the first form input on the fragment.

I've tried using `aria-live` to no avail. I suspect the nature of the SPA interferes with the registration of those live regions (meaning my guess is that they must be registered when the page is rendered, as they don't seem responsive when injected into the DOM). I did not however, chase the answer down a rabbit hole so that is speculative. So *then* I added a class to the target input and tried to use `HTMLElement.focus()`

`document.querySelector('.focus')[0].focus();`

This also did not work. Does anyone know of a reason why I cannot seem to focus on an element that was recently injected into the DOM and is *visible* on the page at the time?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's needed is for your form component to have something defined for when it's [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
const template = `<div>
    <div>
      <inner v-if="showInner" />   
      <button @click="toggle">Toggle inner component</button>
    </div>
</div>`
const inner = {
  name: 'inner',
  template: '<form><input ref="textInput" type="text"/></form>',
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.textInput.focus()
  }
};
new Vue({
  template,
  data: function() {
    return {
      showInner: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.showInner = !this.showInner;
    }
  },
  components: {
    inner
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```